# Bottomappbar not seen properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bottomappbar

I'm trying to put a `bottomAppBar` to `mainActivity`.
So I tried and check lots of stuff in here but couldn't find any solutions.

MainActivity's XML code is below(It has another constraint layout as a parent but didn't add here.)

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorGray"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppbar"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="-10dp"
       />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So after that, I prepared a `bottomappbar_menu.xml` in `menu` directory and I tried to attach this menu to my `MainActivity` file's `OnCreate` method like below:

```
bottomAppbar.replaceMenu(R.menu.bottomappbar_menu)
```

Also `styles.xmsl` is like below,

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

But when I install to phone, it's seen like below. I don't see any menu item:

[image: BottomApbar's screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a problem I had.

Are you using

```
setSupportActionBar(bottomAppBar);
```

together with `replaceMenu`?

In that case, remove `setSupportActionBar` and everything should work.